# Jquery Steps Reload Current Async Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I am trying to reload the current step that I am on. I have 3 steps and I need to reload the page after making changes within it.

I am using the async steps so it loads a url on each step.

In the https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki I am unable to find anything like reload current page.

I need to run the call to get the content for section 
`<section data-mode="async" data-url="/gs-service/viewHealthReport?id={{ inspectionId }}">
                </section>`

Something like #('#section').reloadContent(); to mimic clicking the next button but just reload the current section instead of moving to the next step.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="multipoint-panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <form id="cust-view-vhr-form">
                <input name="inspectionId" type="hidden" value="{{ inspectionId }}">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>Health Report For {{ roData['customer_name'] }}'s {{ roData['ymm'] }}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h3>Repair Date: {{ roDate }}</h3>
                        <h3>Reported Mileage: {{ roData['vehicle_odo'] }}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="view-vhr-form">
                <h3>Repair Overview</h3>
                <section data-mode="async" data-url="/gs-service/viewHealthReport?id={{ inspectionId }}">
                </section>
                <h3>Full Report</h3>
                <section data-mode="async" data-url="/gs-service/viewFullReport?id={{ inspectionId }}">
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit more clarity @Jed. Do you mean you are trying to reload the entire page or a specific section after each step? What do you have so far?

Comment: The content of a specific section I will post the code shortly @Chris

Comment: Excellent. Makes sense. On the callback have you tried jquery append or html? Something like $("#section1").html(Health Report For Jane Doe's Blah); Where you insert id="section1" in the first div next to class ="col"? So basically, when you get customer name back from DB insert it using .html?

Comment: I have created a work around. By reloading div's within the section. This would still be a nice feature to have.